# Logarithmic slider

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

Is it possible to create a logarithmic slider similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5307567/695132) that responds to a change of the variable value?

That is, when the slider is moved, the variable value should update.  When the variable value is changed separately, the slider position should update too.

The ultimate aim is to use this in `Manipulate` and have both a text input and a logarithmic slider input for the same parameter.

---

The post I linked to does not address changing the slider position when the variable is changed elsewhere.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### A reliable composition of elements

Perhaps something like this?  (*Edit:* Fixed to work with `Autorun`.)  Note that the `InputField` label is editable, similar to a normal [`Manipulator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulator.html).  One can also add an additional `InputField[Dynamic @ x]` if a regular [`InputField`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputField.html) is desired.

```
Manipulate[
 x,
 {{x, 1.}, 1., 100.,
  Row[{Slider[Dynamic[Log10[#], (x = 10^#) &], Log10[#2]], " ", 
     InputField[#, Appearance -> "Frameless", BaseStyle -> "Label"]}] &}
 ]
```

[image: Autorun of Manipulate]

It's not a [`Manipulator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulator.html), so no animator/input field.  That's harder, since they (and the label) are built into the front-end implementation of a `Manipulator`.  A [`Trigger`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Trigger.html) and [`InputField`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputField.html) could be added to simulate a `Manipulator`, I suppose.

---

### A proper hack

All right, Kuba, you asked for it. :)

This is based on some spelunking of undocumented functions.  The section titles reflect my feeling that the first is the best and a very good way to go.  (These UI/Manipulate questions never seem to generate much interest in this SE community.  This one wasn't particularly hard, but it did take some time to go through the details.  I hope someone will find it **useful**, which is much more rewarding to me that "upvotes."  In fact, I hope the first one is even more useful.)

The code is long, mainly because I worked out how the options to `Manipulator` are passed to the internal function.  I put it at the end.  I wrote a function `logManipulator` that works (almost exactly) like `Manipulator` (one unimportant thing was left undone).

```
{logManipulator[Dynamic[x], {1., 100.}], InputField[Dynamic@x]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The OP mentioned using it in a `Manipulate` with an input field.  My original answer put the editable field as a label, just as a `Manipulator` does.  However if a separate `InputField` is desired, that it as easy as adding a line to `Manipulate` for it.

To use `logManipulator` in `Manipulate`, one needs to pass a pure `Function` as with any custom control.  Note: the animation below was produce with `Export` via `Autorun`, which interpolates `x` linearly between `10.^-5` and `10.`; the animator, however, when run, interpolates linearly between their logarithms, and the slider moves with constant speed (more or less).

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[t Sin[1/t], {t, -x, x}, PlotRange -> x, ImagePadding -> 10],
 {x, 10.^-5, 10., 
  logManipulator[##, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}, AnimationDirection -> Backward] &},
 {{x, 1.}, Number, InputField},
 AutorunSequencing -> {1}
 ]
```

[image: Autorun of Manipulate]

One can enter a value for `x` in the `InputField` (note the position of the slider):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Code dump

The elements and options of `Manipulator` are nearly each passed as separate arguments to `` FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "Manipulator04"][..] ``.  Only the animator elements in `AppearanceElements -> {..}` are passed together as a list.  Some of the options are passed in other places.  Since the `Manipulator` is wrapped in a `DynamicBox`, I used `With` to inject the values.  I've given the arguments names that correspond more or less to the names of the elements or options.  I hope that is enough of a hint as to how it works.  The basis for the code was the output cell of a simple `Manipulator[Dynamic[x]]` (which can be inspected with the menu command "Cell > Show Expression").

```
ClearAll[logManipulator];
With[{smallerRule = {Large -> Medium, Medium -> Small, Small -> Tiny}},
 logManipulator[Dynamic[x_], range_: {1, 10}, 
   OptionsPattern[Manipulator]] := With[{
    logrange = Log10[range],
    imagesize = OptionValue[ImageSize] /. Automatic -> Medium,
    inputfieldsize = 
     OptionValue[ImageSize] /. Automatic -> Medium /. smallerRule,
    enabled = OptionValue[Enabled],
    continuousaction = OptionValue[ContinuousAction],
    appearance = 
     First[Cases[OptionValue[Appearance], 
        Tiny | Small | Medium | Large] /. {} -> {Automatic}],
    labeled = ! FreeQ[OptionValue[Appearance], "Labeled"] || ! 
       FreeQ[OptionValue[AppearanceElements], "InlineInputField"],
    opener = 
     OptionValue[AppearanceElements] /. {Automatic -> True, 
       All -> True, None -> False, 
       l_List :> (Cases[l, Except["InlineInputField"]] =!= {})},
    inputfield = 
     MatchQ[OptionValue[AppearanceElements], Automatic | All] ||
      ! FreeQ[OptionValue[AppearanceElements], "InputField"],
    appearanceelements = 
     OptionValue[AppearanceElements] /. {Automatic -> All, None -> {},
        l_List :> Cases[l, Except["InlineInputField" | "InputField"]]},
    autoaction = OptionValue[AutoAction],
    exclusions = OptionValue[Exclusions]},
   ReleaseHold@MakeExpression[
     PaneBox[
      DynamicModuleBox[{
        Typeset`open$$ = ! FreeQ[OptionValue[Appearance], "Open"],
        Typeset`paused$$ = OptionValue[PausedTime],
        Typeset`rate$$ = OptionValue[AnimationRate],
        Typeset`dir$$ = OptionValue[AnimationDirection]},
       StyleBox[
        DynamicBox[
         FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "Manipulator04"][
          Dynamic[x],
          Dynamic[Log10[x], (x = 10^#) & ],
          logrange,
          imagesize,
          inputfieldsize,
          enabled,
          continuousaction,
          appearance,
          labeled,
          opener,
          inputfield,
          appearanceelements ,
          autoaction,
          exclusions,
          Dynamic[Typeset`open$$],
          Dynamic[Typeset`paused$$],
          Dynamic[Typeset`rate$$],
          Dynamic[Typeset`dir$$]]],
        DynamicUpdating -> True],
       DynamicModuleValues :> {}],
      BaselinePosition -> (OptionValue[BaselinePosition] /. Automatic -> Baseline),
      ImageMargins -> OptionValue[ImageMargins]],
     StandardForm]]
 ]
```

Comment: Maybe you can post that solution involving cell edition you've mentioned on chat? I will certainly upvote it.

Comment: I do find it useful! I thought you will only post information which box to edit in the cell, I'm impressed. Unfortunately I can't upvote twice.

Comment: Thanks!  I figure coding it could be worked out, only I wasn't motivated to do it until you asked.  I'm glad you find it useful.

Comment: The Michael as I know him ;) +1

Comment: Amazing that you went so deep into undocumented functions!

Comment: Great example and super useful to me. If you're still reading this after 8 years: is there a way to have the label always show numbers in scientific form with a given number of digits? For instance, if I put the slider to 0.001 it shows it as fraction 1/1000 but I would like it to be 1.00e-3 or 1.00 x 10^-3. Thanks a lot for your work!

Comment: @André Thanks. In the first method, you can replace `InputField` by whatever display you want, such as `Dynamic@Pane[ScientificForm[SetPrecision[#, 6] & @@ #], 70]`, where `SetPrecision[#, 6] &@@` could be omitted, `ScientificForm` could be `FortranForm`, etc. In the second, manipulator method, the system automatically constructs the `InputField`, so your options are limited. You can replace the `Dynamic[x]` by `Dynamic[ScientificForm@x, None]`. It can't be edited, and I couldn't find a function for `None` that would allow it to be edited. `FortranForm` does not work either (don't know why).

Answer (score 8):

**with manipulate**

```
Manipulate[
           Framed@y,

           Column@{Slider[Dynamic[Log[10, y], (y = 10^#) &], {1, 3}], 
                   InputField[Dynamic@y]}
          ]
```

**single slider**

```
y=10;    
{
 Slider[Dynamic[Log[10, y], (y = 10^#) &], {1, 3}], 
 Dynamic@y
}
```

Of course, here base is `10` but if it is what You are looking for, I can extend this.

Comment: You need to read more carefully: "When the variable value is changed separately, the slider position should update too."

Comment: @halirutan Have You tried that? Works for me. Try to set `y=123` for example after some sliding done.

Comment: Indeed, I haven't tried. I just looked shortly over your code and saw that you haven't used any text input as asked by Szabolcs. Therefore, and for the simplicity of the approach (which I'm sure Szabolcs would have found by himself) I assumed you missed that part. I'm sorry, I didn't mean to be rude. I was in a hurry and just wanted to tell you, that you missed some parts of the question.

Comment: I'm still not sure whether this is all Szabolcs wanted. Lets wait for a comment of him and if it really is, you can count on my upvote for your answer.

Comment: @halirutan ah, indeed, You're right I have missed "text" part ;) Please take a look at update.

Comment: I also fell for the trap of expecting the solution to be less simple

Comment: @Rojo I do not know what to think since there isn't any  response from Szabolcs.

Comment: Sorry for the unreasonably long delay guys.  This is indeed what I was looking for.  I finally accepted Michael's as a more comprehensive one, but +1 here too.

Answer (score 4):

Here there are two variables `x` and `y` that are coupled together by the `If` statements. So you can change the slider `x` and it changes the `y` value or you can change the input box `y` and it also changes the `x`. The log character of the slider and box are given by the `z=10^x` function, which means that the slider value is the log of `z`.

```
xOld = 0; yOld = 0;
Manipulate[If[10^xOld != 10^x, y = x; xOld = x];
           If[10^yOld != 10^y, x = y; yOld = y]; z = 10^x, {x, 1, 10}, {y}]
```

[image]

This basically extends Michael Pilat's answer to the linked question to the case of two controls (the slider and the input box).