# Slider with non-linear behavior

Tags: gui-construction, interactive

I am trying to develop a small tool and I am stuck on a very simple problem.

This how I want it to look:

[image]

I have

```
minValue = steps = 100.000
valueRange = 500.000.000 - 100.000
newPercent = where the circle is right now (0-100%)
newValue = minValue + (valueRange * newPercent / 100.0);
```

The range is very big, and it is very hard to set the right value at the beginning, but when the value is above 200 million, I don't care about 100000. So I wont to make it exponential; e.g., $x=y^2$

That what I was thinking.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e9onr7i6926

I want to make the first steps with 100.000 and them more and more.

Maybe like this?

http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ev8h6m2vulq

Maybe I am totally wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at [logarithmic slider](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28457/5478), try to implement your ideas and if you get stuck, we will help you for sure :)

Comment: p.s. pressed Alt makes Slider less sensitive.

Comment: On OS X pressing Shift+Options (I guess Shift+Alt on other systems) makes the slider move even slower.  I can almost control the 5th digit after the decimal point in a range of (0, 1) like this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized and abandoned.