# How can I make 1+$MachineEpsilon not look like 1?

Tags: output-formatting, machine-precision, display

I undarstand that `1+$MachineEpsilon` is actually not equal `1`. However, it persists to look like it was equal `1.`

```
In[1]:= 1 + $MachineEpsilon

Out[1]= 1.
```

This is inappropriate in some cases, as in the following example:

```
Manipulate[
 Row@{TraditionalForm@HoldForm@Defer@ (1/(x - 1)), "\[Equal]", 
  TraditionalForm@(1/(x - 1))}, {x, 1 + $MachineEpsilon, 2, 
 Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

The above input gives this:

[image]

Which very much looks like as if we had some division by zero.

How to fix this? How to display this 1+$MachineEpsilon more accurately?

So far, I've tried this:

```
In[3]:= N[1 + $MachineEpsilon, $MachinePrecision]

Out[3]= 1.
```

I fail to understand the above output - `1+$MachineEpsilon` is supposed to be a machine number, and therefore it should be accurately representable with `$MachinePrecision` digits of precision, shouldn't it?

Comment: Perhaps `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintPrecision -> 17]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sadly, no. See: http://i61.tinypic.com/f5dgrk.jpg The formula result is ridiculously accurate, but `1.` persists.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oddly enough, outside Manipulate the precision is correct: http://i57.tinypic.com/krns3.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the input field that is used to display the current value of `x` has its own formatting rules and altering them seems difficult.  It does not follow `PrintPrecision` (as in `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintPrecision -> 17]`, which works for output in an output cell).

So a workaround is to specify the `Precision` of the displayed `x`, such that the normal formatting rule shows enough digits. `SetPrecision[x, 17]` would be sufficient.

```
Manipulate[
 Row@{TraditionalForm@HoldForm@Defer@(1/(x - 1)), "\[Equal]", 
   TraditionalForm@(1/(x - 1))},
 {x, 1 + $MachineEpsilon, 2, 
   Manipulator[
     Dynamic[SetPrecision[x, 17], (x = #) &], {1 + $MachineEpsilon, 2},
      Appearance -> "Labeled"] &}]
```

See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28457/logarithmic-slider/28501#28501) for some further insight into how the `Manipulator` is formatted.

Comment: Many thanks, it works! BTW: `SetPrecision[1 + $MachineEpsilon, MachinePrecision + 1]` gives `1.0000000000000002`, as it should; but `SetPrecision[1 + $MachineEpsilon, MachinePrecision]` gives `1.` Why? `1+$MachineEpsilon` is a machine number, so why can't it be displayed with machine precision? And why does `N[1 + $MachineEpsilon, 100]` still give `1.`?

Comment: @gaazkam The precision of `1 + $MachineEpsilon` is `MachinePrecision`, so `SetPrecision[1 + $MachineEpsilon, MachinePrecision]` does nothing. `SetPrecision[x, $MachinePrecision]` almost works, but not quite, because `1 + $MachineEpsilon` is a little bigger than `1`.  You could get by with `$MachinePrecision + 0.1`.  It's a bit complicated for a comment, but machine numbers are represented with a finite number of bits and the notion of `Precision` is relative to the size of `x`. There are discrete jumps in precision when the exponent changes. `N[x, 100]` won't increase the precision of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying the precision, you can also just modify the display of the number:

```
1 + $MachineEpsilon // FullForm
(* 1.0000000000000002` *)

1 + $MachineEpsilon // InputForm
(* 1.0000000000000002 *)
```

So something like this could work for you:

```
Manipulate[
  Grid[{{TraditionalForm@HoldForm@Defer@x, "\[Equal]", InputForm@x},
        {TraditionalForm@HoldForm@Defer@(1/(x - 1)), "\[Equal]", TraditionalForm@(1/(x - 1))}}],
  {x, 1 + $MachineEpsilon, 2}]
```